# Java custom comparator does not work

Tags: java

Hey I want to compare my own objects so that i can sort them inside my arrayList, my object has 3 fields, one of them is int
my comparator code looks like

```
public class ImageComparator implements Comparator<Obj> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Obj 1, Obj 2) {

        return 1.Id > 2.Id ? 1 : 0;
    }
}

Collections.sort(myList, new ImageComparator());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Variable names cannot start with digits.

Comment: Variables can't be digits like that.

Comment: Does it even compile ? AFAIK 1 and 2 are not legal identifiers in java

Comment: Look at the compiler error message - it should help you to figure it out...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missed -1 value,

try instead of condition a standard method, for example:

```
public class ImageComparator implements Comparator<Obj> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Obj o1, Obj o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1.Id, o2.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `Integer.compare()`.

Comment: Best answer, short and clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to check 3 cases here (`<`, `>`, `=`).

```
public class ImageComparator implements Comparator<Obj> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Obj o1, Obj o2) {

        if (o1.Id > o2.Id) return 1;
        else if (o1.Id < o2.Id) return -1;
        else return 0;

    }
}

Collections.sort(myList, new ImageComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

A comparator's `compare` method returns 1, -1, or 0 if object 1 is greater than, less than, or equal to object 2.  So, you need to check these 3 cases and return the correct value for your object's ID value.

```
public int compare(Obj ob1, Obj obj2){
    if(obj1.Id > obj2.Id)
        return 1;
    if(obj1.Id < obj2.Id)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you may not use numbers as variable names. Then take a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29): return "a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second."

Answer (score -1):

You can't use a digit as the first letter in `variable/method/class names`. for more variable naming rules [Click Here](http://www.c4learn.com/java/java-variable-naming-rules/)

```
public class ImageComparator implements Comparator<Obj> {
    @Override
    public int compare(obj obj1, obj obj2) {
        return ((obj)obj1).Id - ((obj)obj2).Id;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's implementing `Comparator<Obj>`, so there's no need to cast.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Ok master. forgot about it.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
 return v1.Id < v2.Id ? -1 : v1.Id > v2.Id ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Please don't do this. Nesting the ternary operator makes for cryptic code.